# Telepat API Doc -Create App

Tags: telepat

I have probably multiple newbie questions but I am unsure about how to work with telepat based on just the document.

1. While creating an APP, we are expected to give a Key. However the field name is keys. Is there any reason for it? I am assuming that it would have to be unique but document does not mention if that is the case or the error we should expect in case the rule is violated.
2. Referring to http://docs.telepat.io/api.html#api-Admin-AdminCreateContext Admin Create does not seem to require authentication even when doing it from API. It also misses the response on success. Just a 200 may be sufficient but..
3. There is no way to get App ID. What am I missing?

Comment: kindly let us know more about your current environment and we'll try to assist further

Answer (score 4):

First of all, what version of Telepat are you using ? Changes to the infrastructure happen often. The latest version is 0.2.5 (although I'd try to download from develop branch since improvements and bug-fixes appear on a day-by-day basis).

1. You can add multiple API keys for an application and distribute them in whatever way you want. The system is not bothered if you add a key that already exists at the moment.
2. May be because of old Telepat build. Can't get into detail with this.
3. `admin/app/create` returns the application object, including its ID. Also `/admin/apps` returns a list of all applications you have.